# Large touch screen capability

Tags: touchscreen, operating-systems

Would a Hanns.G HT231HPB have 10 point touch screen capability when using a PI 3B running Window 10 IOT (Raspbian does not)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is yes, but the set up isn't straight forward...
I eventually managed to get IOT to accept a deployment of an app I was building and then plumbed it into the display, comparing the touch sensitivity to another PI running the app and Raspbian, so answer was gained through experimentation.

Comment: Could you elaborate on how? Sharing your solution is great, but without the steps you used, this isn't really an answer that could help others. You should [edit] this with a brief description of what you did if you can.